# MongoDBのサービスを常駐できない

Tags: linux, centos, mongodb

**現象**：
　serviceコマンドからのスタートが出来ない。

```
$ service mongod start    [失敗]
```

**試したこと**：
　lockファイルの削除、DBの修復

```
$ rm -f /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock /usr/local/var/mongod/mongod.lock
$ mongod --repair --dbpath=/data/db/
```

**現状**：
　- mongodコマンドを打つと、実行中には出来ます。
　- 別のシェルを立ち上げて、mongoコマンドでシェルを起動することも出来ました。
　- `$ service mongod status`とすると停止状態です。
　- psコマンド、netstatコマンドで確認してもポートかぶりや実は動いている・・・
　　といったことは確認できませんでした。

**設定ファイル**：
　bind_ipの変更とipv6=trueの追記をしました。

```
bind_ip=192.168.XX.XX
ipv6=true
```

**環境**：
　Vagrant
　host:windows8.1
　guest:CentOS6.6
　MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
　MongoDB db version: 2.6.10

以上です、何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら
ご教授願います。

追記します。

**エラーログ**：
シェル上は特に何も出ずです。

```
[root@localhost log]# service mongod start
Starting mongod:                                           [失敗]
[root@localhost log]#
```

mongoDBのログファイルも更新されていませんでした。

ただ、/var/log/secureに以下のエラーログが吐かれていました。

```
Aug  5 07:16:41 localhost runuser: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by vagrant(uid=0)
Aug  5 07:16:41 localhost runuser: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
```

**実行ログ**：
`bash -x /etc/init.d/mongod start`を実行してみました。
始めて使ったコマンドなのでちんぷんかんぷんですが；
頑張ってみます。

```
+ . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
++ TEXTDOMAIN=initscripts
++ umask 022
++ PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
++ export PATH
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ COLUMNS=80
++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ /sbin/consoletype
++ CONSOLETYPE=pty
++ '[' -f /etc/sysconfig/i18n -a -z '' -a -z '' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
++ unset LANGSH_SOURCED
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -f /etc/sysconfig/init ']'
++ . /etc/sysconfig/init
+++ BOOTUP=color
+++ RES_COL=60
+++ MOVE_TO_COL='echo -en \033[60G'
+++ SETCOLOR_SUCCESS='echo -en \033[0;32m'
+++ SETCOLOR_FAILURE='echo -en \033[0;31m'
+++ SETCOLOR_WARNING='echo -en \033[0;33m'
+++ SETCOLOR_NORMAL='echo -en \033[0;39m'
+++ PROMPT=yes
+++ AUTOSWAP=no
+++ ACTIVE_CONSOLES='/dev/tty[1-6]'
+++ SINGLE=/sbin/sushell
++ '[' pty = serial ']'
++ __sed_discard_ignored_files='/\(~\|\.bak\|\.orig\|\.rpmnew\|\.rpmorig\|\.rpmsave\)$/d'
+ CONFIGFILE=/etc/mongod.conf
+ OPTIONS=' -f /etc/mongod.conf'
+ SYSCONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/mongod
++ awk '-F[:=]' -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^[[:blank:]]*dbpath[[:blank:]]*[:=][[:blank:]]*/{print $2}' /etc/mongod.conf
++ tr -d '[:blank:]'
+ DBPATH=/var/lib/mongo
++ tr -d '[:blank:]'
++ awk '-F[:=]' -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^[[:blank:]]*pidfilepath[[:blank:]]*[:=][[:blank:]]*/{print $2}' /etc/mongod.conf
+ PIDFILE=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
++ dirname /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
+ PIDDIR=/var/run/mongodb
+ mongod=/usr/bin/mongod
+ MONGO_USER=mongod
+ MONGO_GROUP=mongod
+ '[' -f /etc/sysconfig/mongod ']'
+ . /etc/sysconfig/mongod
+ NUMACTL_ARGS=--interleave=all
+ which numactl
+ NUMACTL=
+ RETVAL=0
+ case "$1" in
+ start
+ '[' '!' -d /var/run/mongodb ']'
+ ulimit -f unlimited
+ ulimit -t unlimited
+ ulimit -v unlimited
+ ulimit -n 64000
+ ulimit -m unlimited
+ ulimit -u 64000
+ echo -n 'Starting mongod: '
Starting mongod: + daemon --user mongod --check /usr/bin/mongod ' /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf >/dev/null 2>&1'
+ local gotbase= force= nicelevel corelimit
+ local pid base= user= nice= bg= pid_file=
+ local cgroup=
+ nicelevel=0
+ '[' --user '!=' -user ']'
+ case $1 in
+ user=mongod
+ shift 2
+ '[' --check '!=' -check ']'
+ case $1 in
+ base=/usr/bin/mongod
+ gotbase=yes
+ shift 2
+ '[' ' /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf >/dev/null 2>&1' '!=' ' /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf >/dev/null 2>&1' ']'
+ '[' -z yes ']'
+ __pids_var_run /usr/bin/mongod ''
+ local base=mongod
+ local pid_file=/var/run/mongod.pid
++ /usr/bin/dirname /var/run/mongod.pid
+ local pid_dir=/var/run
+ local binary=
+ '[' -d /var/run -a '!' -r /var/run ']'
+ pid=
+ '[' -f /var/run/mongod.pid ']'
+ return 3
+ '[' -n '' -a -z '' ']'
+ corelimit='ulimit -S -c 0'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' color = verbose -a -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z mongod ']'
+ runuser -s /bin/bash mongod -c 'ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ;  /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf >/dev/null 2>&1'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ failure '/usr/bin/mongod 起動'
+ local rc=1
+ '[' color '!=' verbose -a -z '' ']'
+ echo_failure
+ '[' color = color ']'
+ echo -en '\033[60G'
                                                           + echo -n '['
[+ '[' color = color ']'
+ echo -en '\033[0;31m'
+ echo -n $'\345\244\261\346\225\227'
失敗+ '[' color = color ']'
+ echo -en '\033[0;39m'
+ echo -n ']'
]+ echo -ne '\r'
+ return 1
+ '[' -x /bin/plymouth ']'
+ /bin/plymouth --details
+ return 1
+ RETVAL=1
+ echo

+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ exit 1
```

**startのファンクションを変更後**：

/etc/init.d/mongodのstart()を以下のように変更。

```
#  daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" --check $mongod "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"
  daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" --check $mongod "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS"
```

シェルで`service mongod start`を実行。

```
Starting mongod: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 4985
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
                                                           [失敗]
```

**設定ファイル(/etc/mongod.conf)**：

```
# mongod.conf

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

# fork and run in background
fork=true

#port=27017

dbpath=/var/lib/mongo

# location of pidfile
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
# bind_ip=127.0.0.1
bind_ip=192.168.33.10
ipv6=true

# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal=true
 journal=true
 smallfiles=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu=true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth=true
#auth=true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose=true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck=true

# Enable db quota management
#quota=true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog=0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints=true

# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
#httpinterface=true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting=true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan=true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc=true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize=<size>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify the replica set name here
#replSet=setname
# maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024
# path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

**ファイル詳細**
　ひとまず、`find / -name mongo` で検索をかけて、必要になりそうなものの権限を調べました。

```
■ /root/
-rw-------.  1 root root     0  8月  5 00:28 2015 .mongorc.js
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     0  8月  6 08:32 2015 mongod.log

■ /var/lib/
drwxrw-rw-.  3 mongod  mongod 4096  8月  6 02:05 2015 mongo

■ /var/lib/mongo/:
合計 81936
drwxrw-rw-.  2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  6 02:06 2015 journal
-rwxrw-rw-.  1 mongod mongod 67108864  8月  6 01:42 2015 local.0
-rwxrw-rw-.  1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 01:42 2015 local.ns

■ /var/lib/mongo/journal:
合計 2228244
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod  134217728  8月  6 02:06 2015 prealloc.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 1073741824  8月  4 11:56 2015 prealloc.1
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 1073741824  8月  4 11:56 2015 prealloc.2

■ /var/run/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mongod  mongod  4096  8月  6 02:04 2015 mongodb

■ /var/log/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mongod mongod   4096  8月  6 08:34 2015 mongodb

■ /var/log/mongodb
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    2278  8月  6 08:34 2015 mongod.log
-rw-r-----. 1 mongod mongod 46307  8月  4 14:24 2015 mongod.log.2015-08-04T11-51-01
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    7858  8月  6 02:06 2015 mongod.log.2015-08-05T23-54-14
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    3845  8月  6 01:54 2015 mongod.log.2015-08-06T00-02-05
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    3845  8月  6 02:02 2015 mongod.log.2015-08-06T00-02-51
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    1741  8月  6 02:02 2015 mongod.log.2015-08-06T06-29-24
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    2278  8月  6 08:29 2015 mongod.log.2015-08-06T06-34-35

■ /usr/local/var/
drwxrw-rw-.  8 mongod mongod 4096  8月  6 11:28 2015 mongod

■ /usr/local/var/mongod
drwxrw-rw-. 2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  6 11:28 2015 _tmp
drwxrw-rw-. 2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  7 02:09 2015 journal
drwxrw-rw-. 2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  5 00:11 2015 local
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 67108864  8月  6 10:40 2015 local.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 10:40 2015 local.ns
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 14:55 2015 mongo_project_development.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 14:55 2015 mongo_project_development.ns
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod        0  8月  7 02:09 2015 mongod.lock
drwxrw-rw-. 2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  5 14:43 2015 sampledb
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 67108864  8月  6 10:47 2015 sampledb.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 10:40 2015 sampledb.ns
drwxrw-rw-. 2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  5 14:43 2015 test
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 67108864  8月  6 10:40 2015 test.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 10:40 2015 test.ns
drwxrw-rw-. 2 mongod mongod     4096  8月  5 14:42 2015 testdb
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 67108864  8月  6 10:40 2015 testdb.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 16777216  8月  6 10:40 2015 testdb.ns

■ /usr/local/var/mongod/_tmp:空

■ /usr/local/var/mongod/journal:
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 134217728  8月  7 02:09 2015 prealloc.0
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 134217728  8月  6 02:10 2015 prealloc.1
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 mongod mongod 134217728  8月  6 02:10 2015 prealloc.2

■ /usr/local/var/mongod/local:空

■ /usr/local/var/mongod/sampledb:空

■ /usr/local/var/mongod/test:空

■ /usr/local/var/mongod/testdb:空

■ /usr/share/man/manX/
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  16592  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongo.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  39099  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongod.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  16840  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongodump.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  19099  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongoexport.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  14153  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongofiles.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  16065  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongoimport.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  13347  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongooplog.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   5825  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongoperf.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  16644  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongorestore.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  23535  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongos.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  15941  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongostat.1
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  12415  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongotop.1

■ /usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    11957616  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongo
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23937328  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongod
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23828304  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongodump
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23774576  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongoexport
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23823616  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongofiles
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23798992  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongoimport
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23766384  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongooplog
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23580768  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongoperf
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23868944  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongorestore
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    18540080  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongos
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23819824  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongostat
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    23762096  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongotop

■ /etc/mongod.conf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1598  8月  6 01:52 2015 mongod.conf

■ /etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  2719  8月  6 08:20 2015 mongod

■ /etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod.bk
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  2644  8月  6 08:19 2015 mongod.bk

■ /etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K15mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  4 11:33 2015 K15mongod -> ../init.d/mongod

■ /etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K15mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  4 11:33 2015 K15mongod -> ../init.d/mongod

■ /etc/rc.d/rc4.d/S85mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  5 00:20 2015 S85mongod -> ../init.d/mongod

■ /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S85mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  5 00:20 2015 S85mongod -> ../init.d/mongod
■ /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S85mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  5 00:20 2015 S85mongod -> ../init.d/mongod
■ /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S85mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  5 00:20 2015 S85mongod -> ../init.d/mongod
■ /etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K15mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16  8月  4 11:33 2015 K15mongod -> ../init.d/mongod

■ /etc/sysconfig/mongod
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   47  5月 19 17:25 2015 mongod
```

**SELinux**

```
$ setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
$ service mongod start
Starting mongod: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 3806
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
                                                           [失敗]
```

Comment: startが失敗するタイミングでログになにか出力されていれば追記してくださいますか。

Comment: @take88 ありがとうございます。

調査し、投稿に追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。残念ながらログに有益な情報は無いようですね。起動スクリプトをトレースしてどこで失敗しているか調べるのはどうでしょう。「bash -x /etc/init.d/mongod start」とやると起動スクリプトの処理内容を追跡できます。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。「bash -x /etc/init.d/mongod start」のコマンドは初めて知りました；実行結果を追記しました。もう少し探ってみます。

Comment: runuser -s /bin/bash mongod... のところで失敗してますね。これは /etc/init.d/mongod の start() 関数の処理で mongod デーモンを起動するところです。デフォルトだと標準出力等を捨てているので、エラーメッセージが表示されてないのかもしれません。「/etc/init.d/mongod」ファイルをエディタで編集して「daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"」のところを「daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS"」に書き換えて、スタートすると何かメッセージが表示されないでしょうか。

Comment: 結果を追記しました。エラーメッセージが表示されました。一応エラーログも再度確認しましたが特に何も出されてませんでした・・・。

Comment: パーミッションが怪しいですね。 /etc/mongod.confの内容と、設定なさっている各種ファイルやフォルダのパーミッション情報を追記していただけますか？ また、selinuxを有効にしている場合は「setenforce 0」コマンドで一時的に無効にしてstartするとなにか変化はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 遅くなりまして申し訳ございません。パーミッション情報とselinuxの件、試してみました。

Comment: $ sudo service mongod start  としてもだめですか?

Comment: @Hideki ありがとうございます！`sudo service mongod start`でも実行できません・・・。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

調査結果の記載ありがとうございます。
ログファイルのオーナーがrootになっておりmongodユーザの書き込み権限がありませんね。
これはおそらく root で mongod を起動したときに作られたのだと思います。
service start mongod した場合は mongod ユーザプロセスが実行されますので ログに追加書き込みができてない状態だと思われます。

対処としてはchownでファイルオーナーをmongodに変更するのがいいと思います。

```
# chown mongod:mongod /var/log/mongod.log
# service mongod start
```

Comment: 動きました！！胸のつかえが取れた気分です・・・！長い間ご協力して頂きありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

一般論として、対話シエルでは動くけどinitを起源とするプロセスで動かそうとするとエラーになる場合、SELinuxを疑うのが早道です。(そもそもSELinuxはデーモン乗っ取りを主な防御対象としているので)

mongoDBのサイト http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/ に対処方法が書かれていますね。真ん中あたりのConfigure SELinuxの3項目のうちどれか一つをやればいいようです。(個人的にはSELinuxを停止させるのは問題を先送りにしているだけなので3番目をお勧めいたします)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
take88さんの方で教えていただいた`setenforce 0`で無効にしてみましたが、
実行はできませんでした・・・。
念の為、ご紹介いただいた対処法も実施しておきます。

「 **対話シエルでは動くけどinitを起源とするプロセスで動かそうとするとエラーになる場合、SELinuxを疑うのが早道** 」このことは頭に入れておきます！ありがとうございます！